# Reason for having additional "type" table of all possible string values?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I've been looking over some sample schemas, and here's something I've seen done several times, but being new to MySQL I'm not sure why. Say I've got a table for items:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
  itemID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  itemType VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (itemID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_item_itemType FOREIGN KEY (itemType) REFERENCES itemType(name)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Why would you need `itemType` to be a foreign key to another table that lists all the possible item types? Would it prevent typos if the entered value wasn't in the other table? The other table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE itemType (
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (name),
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
INSERT INTO itemType (name) VALUES ('gloves');
INSERT INTO itemType (name) VALUES ('boots');
INSERT INTO itemType (name) VALUES ('ring');
```

Comment: Note also that `CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY ...` doesn't actually do anything at all when `ENGINE = MyISAM`, since MyISAM doesn't actually support foreign key constraints.   There is no reason anyone should be using MyISAM.

Comment: I thought MyISAM was supposed to be faster if the table is going to be read a lot more than it will be written to? Would it be appropriate for the reference table, which will hardly ever be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the idea here is to restrict what `itemType`s can be used in the `item` table to only those in the `itemType` table, while at the same time avoiding having to do a JOIN with the `itemType` table to get the actual value whenever you `SELECT` from the item table. It's a kind of denormalization in order to optimize `SELECT` statements. This comes at a cost of needing more storage space since every `item` record will have the full `itemType` name, potentially as long as 255 characters.

With a normalized approach you would have tables defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
  ...
  itemTypeID int unsigned NOT NULL,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT fk_item_itemType FOREIGN KEY (itemTypeID) REFERENCES itemType(itemTypeID)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE itemType (
  itemTypeID int unsigned NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (itemTypeID),
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

However, when `SELECT`ing from the `item` table you would now have to do a `JOIN` in order to display the itemType:

```
SELECT i.itemID, i.name, it.name "itemTypeName"
FROM item i 
  INNER JOIN itemType it USING (itemTypeID);
```

Another solution to this is using an ENUM and avoid the `itemType` table altogether:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
  itemID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  itemType ENUM('gloves', 'boots', 'ring') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (itemID)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

The drawback of this approach is that you would have to `ALTER` the table whenever you want to add a new `itemType`.

Answer (score 1):

This is implementing an *enumeration* type: making sure that the value is only ever one from the specified list.

Some databases natively support enums: see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html for example.

Even why there is native support, you might still implement the behaviour using a table as in your example, so that the range of valid values can be altered later without a schema change.